# Data appears below in each child div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a page in which when an anchor tag is click it pulls in data from the URL associated with that anchor.  I want the data pulled in to only display in the div class popup associated with that anchor.  Each anchor and div class popup are in a parent div named employee.  When it is click now it pull in the data but to every div class popup on the page. I have tried .find and .children but neither is working.  Can anyone help me?

```js
    (function($) {


      function find_page_number(element) {
        return parseInt(element.html());
      }

      $('.leadership').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        page = find_page_number($(this).clone());

        var memberSrc = $(this).attr('href');

        $.ajax({

          url: memberSrc,
          type: 'get',
          dataType: 'html',
          data: {
            action: 'ajax_pagination',
            query_vars: ajaxpagination.query_vars,
            page: page
          },
          success: function(html) {
            $(".popup").empty();
            $('.popup').append($(html).find('.single-member').html());
          }

        });


      })
    })(jQuery);
```

```html
<div class="employee">
  
  <a class="leadership" href="different for each">
 
    <img src="#" />
    
  </a>
  
  <div class="popup"></div>
  
</div>

<div class="employee">
  
  <a class="leadership" href="different for each">
 
    <img src="#" />
    
  </a>
  
  <div class="popup"></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Only God know what is the result of this ajax request ( `$('.popup').append($(html).find('.single-member').html());` what's `html` var has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're using the class selector `.popup` and you have multiple popups on the page.

To get a reference to the popup you want, you can go up to the parent and look for a popup in the element, or look at the siblings of `.leadership`.

Something like this may work:

```
$('.leadership').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    page = find_page_number($(this).clone());

    var memberSrc = $(this).attr('href');

    // Get a reference to your parent employee div
    var parent = $(this).parent();

    $.ajax({

      url: memberSrc,
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'html',
      data: {
        action: 'ajax_pagination',
        query_vars: ajaxpagination.query_vars,
        page: page
      },
      success: function(html) {
        var popup = parent.find(".popup");
        popup.empty();
        popup.append($(html).find('.single-member').html());
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do it for you - you need to target the child popup tag with `.find()`

```
 $('.leadership').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this).parent();
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    page = find_page_number($(this).clone());

    var memberSrc = $(this).attr('href');

    $.ajax({

      url: memberSrc,
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'html',
      data: {
        action: 'ajax_pagination',
        query_vars: ajaxpagination.query_vars,
        page: page
      },
      success: function(html) {
        var popup = $this.find(".popup");
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        popup.empty();
        popup.append($(html).find('.single-member').html());
      }
```